# Windows phone application dependency error

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build one of windows phone project, and the following error shows up every time i build it.

> Error 7   The "Microsoft.Phone.Build.Tasks.ValidateWMAppManifest" task
>   could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for
>   Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Phone.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
>   declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
>   available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

The code was running earlier.

I aam trying to run it on my windows 8.1 phone (which I believe should not be the reason for this error) and the only thing i did extra was to install WPToolkit using nuget.

Answer (score 1):

To Resolve this issue,Use the Uninstall or change a program" feature in Control Panel to repair `Windows Phone SDK 8.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error after Windows10 Millenium update and resolve it by enabling .Net FrameWork 3.5 in Windows features.

[image: Windows Features .Net framework 3.5 enable]

Note that you should reboot you computer after enabling .Net 3.5.

More information about installing and enabling .Net Framework 3.5 you could find in article [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx)

> You can enable the .NET Framework 3.5 yourself through Control Panel. This option requires an Internet connection. 
>   Press the Windows key  on your keyboard, type Windows Features, and press Enter. This brings up the Turn Windows features on or off dialog box. Alternately, open Control Panel, click on the Programs items, and then click on “Turn Windows features on or off” under Programs and Features.
>   Select the .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) check box, press OK, and reboot your computer if prompted.
>   You do not need to select the child items for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) HTTP activation unless you are a developer who requires WCF script and handler mapping functionality.